# requested resource is not available

Tags: jsf

I am using JSF in one of my application and the scenario is as follows:

1.I have a `pages` folder under `WEB_INF`

2.Inside `pages` I have `a.jsp`

3.When I deploy this application with the local tomcat it says "The requested resource (/pages/a.jsp) is not available."

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaeehttp://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
         <display-name>Sample_Proj</display-name>
         <welcome-file-list>
             <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
             <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
             <welcome-file>AddUser.jsp</welcome-file>
             <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
             <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
             <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
         </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

Is there anything else i need to add into web.xml?
The below url is what I'm using to hit the page:
http://localhost:8080/Sample_Proj/WEB-INF/page/AddUser.jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsp files / folders should exist in the root of the web project and not in the WEB-INF folder, i.e.:

/pages/a.jsp
/WEB-INF/...

Your web.xml file is very much incomplete when it comes to a JSF web project. I would recommend reading the Java EE 6 tutorial, you can read through [this chapter](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnadr.html) on getting started with web applications